# Change visibility of xlim

Tags: r

I am trying to do a plot from my df from the years 1998-2018 but I can not change the visibility of my x-axis. My plotting function at the moment looks like this:

```
plot(df$Year, df$percentage_of_RNAi,
     ylim=range(c(df$percentage_of_RNAi-sdev, df$percentage_of_RNAi+sdev)),
     pch=19, xlab="Years", ylab="Mean of [%] of RNAi research",
     main="Mean per year of RNAi research \n as [%] of total research in the EU", col = ifelse(RNAi_research_EU$Year > 2011, "blue", "red") )
```

The function gives me a nice plot but only shows the years 2000, 2005, 2010 and 2015 on the x-axis. I would, however like to see all years, preferably written vertically. I am kinda new to R, so I am not really sure on how to tackle this problem...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about ticks / tick marks?

Comment: For the vertical labels on the x-axis see the argument `las` here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.1/topics/par

Comment: In base r plotting, to get a custom x axis you will need to suppress the x axis when you first draw the plot, then use the `axis()` function to create the axis with the proper limits and ticks. See https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html -- note that you still will need to set `xlim=c(1998,2018)` in your first call to `plot()`.

Comment: The axis() did the trick, thanks a lot!